# NGXS @Select in service is causing issues

Tags: select, state, ngxs

I am using NGXS in my angular app, and in some of my services I need to select state before returning data.
Seems pretty easy, I made field like this:

```
@Select(AuthState.token) token$!: Observable<string | null>;
```

and used it like this:

```
public getFieldDefinitions(): Observable<ApiFieldDefinition[]> {
    return this.token$
        .pipe(mergeMap(token => of([{}])));
}
```

This service is used in state like so:

```
@Action(FieldDefinitionsGet)
get(ctx: StateContext<FieldDefinitionsStateModel>, action: FieldDefinitionsGet) {
    return this.fieldDefinitionsService.getFieldDefinitions()
        .pipe(tap(d => ctx.setState(
            patch({
                fieldDefinitions: d
            })
        )))
        .pipe(tap(d => console.log('fieldDefinitions', d)));
}
```

The problem is that state is never set. Service returns data `setState` method is invoked, but state is not applied. In console I can see action was started but it is never finished:
[image]

Any clue what may cause the issue?

Everything works normally when I use `selectSnapshot` instead.

Comment: I ran into th esame problem. Looks like there is some compatibility issues between angular 13 and NGXS

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your http call isn't actually happening. Can you validate that the setState method is being called?

Just my opinion, but that is a very.... *interesting* way of setting a header. In my opinion it would be so much easier to just use an angular http interceptor, as that's what they are intended for.

https://angular.io/guide/http#setting-default-headers

Comment: I use interceptors in some cases, but it is not about interceptors. `setState` is being called. Funny thing is that service doesn't event have do http request, with simple `of` same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that when you use selectors, the data is immutable, causing the selector to fail. When using `selectSnapshot`, you are receiving a copy of what is in your state, which allows you to mutate the data.